# How to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Windows 8?

Tags: boot, usb, 14.04, windows-8

I own HP J110TX Laptop running Windows 8 on it. I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS along side windows. I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386 iso. I tried creating bootable USB drive through different softwares available online. It succeeds till here, but when I try to boot from USB it fails. It directly boots to Windows.

I have changed by boot order and given priority to USB. But still it fails..Dunno where its going wrong..

Kindly see the attached image of boot options.

[image]

---

Thanx for the reply..I tried both the methods but cudnt succeed. I am really not sure where it going wrong..I also disabled fastboot but problem persists.

I dont think anything is wrong with the iso coz Universal USB installed did check for its integrity before making it bootable..

What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 1):

Install the Linux Live USB Creator from http://linuxliveusb.com/. Open the application and click the "Download" button from the second box and select "Ubuntu 14.04 KDE" (64 or 32 bit depending on what you want.) from the drop down menu. Pop in a USB and follow the steps. Be sure to check the "Format Key" Check box. It can't boot with other files on the Key. Click the "Install" button. Boot your laptop and press F9. It should say "F9... Change Boot Order" When it boots into the menu, select the USB from the menu and press enter. This should work. Your ISO may have been bad.

Comment: Additionaly you may format your usb drive to fat32. In Linux Live USB there is also option to omit downloading iso and simply installing from already downloaded image.

Comment: Indeed, but the Download option is safer and failsafe on good internet connections.

Comment: Thanx for the reply..I tried both the methods but cudnt succeed. I am really not sure where it going wrong..I also disabled fastboot but problem persists.

I dont think anything is wrong with the iso coz Universal USB installed did check for its integrity before making it bootable..

What could be the problem?

Comment: Bad USB could be a problem. Try getting a new one. That or you could extract the USB to a DVD and run that, just make sure the install type is "Live Mode Only"

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. create a **partition** of hard disk after watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXn2CQkURgo). Give 100gb for ubuntu.
2. **switch off fastboot** in windows. (use google search if you don't know how)
3. load ubuntu 14.04 **bootable pendrive** or a **cd** according to [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) link.
4. now, **insert the pendrive** or the **cd** and click on **power** and **restart** while holding **shift** key.
5. then click on "usb" and then click on first option that is available. (not sure what it says)
6. then click on **try ubuntu** or **install ubuntu**.
7. then follow the steps. in step 3 (i think) it will give you options to clear hard dive (i.e. delete ubuntu) or **other**. choose **other**.
8. the give the following memory for each: **ext4 /** :40gb, **ext4 /home**: 50gb, **ext2 /boot**: 500mb and downset boot thing to **boot partiton**.
9. then you are done. just follow steps.

hope it was helpful.

Comment: You forget the SWAP (at least RAM size for hibernate).  `/home` and `/boot` partition are optional.

Comment: Thanx for the reply..I tried both the methods but cudnt succeed. I am really not sure where it going wrong..I also disabled fastboot but problem persists.

I dont think anything is wrong with the iso coz Universal USB installed did check for its integrity before making it bootable..

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have also HP lap with Windows 8.1 and AMD graphics .
In your case plz do this steps
1. Disable secure boot
2.disable fast boot
3. create a separate partition in C drive by shrinking that 
4.create live cd/usb
5. and installed it
here is a video plz check this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU
have safe and enjoyable ubuntu service

from one User of Ubuntu