# How to Install Ubuntu in my Windows laptop

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I have downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file and I am new to the Linux and in learning phase.

How can I setup Ubuntu in my laptop?

Comment: Was it pre-installed with Windows 8?

Comment: See [this] (http://askubuntu.com/a/469722/281989) link.  Follow the steps.

Comment: Looks like an incomplete question. Elaborate!

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps.

1. create a partition for your hard disk. Give 100gb for
   ubuntu.
2. switch off fastboot in windows. by going to power settings, click on **change what power buttons do** and the deselect **turn on fast startup**. (use google search if you don't know
   how)
3. load ubuntu 14.04 bootable pendrive or a cd according to
   [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
   link.
4. now, insert the pendrive or the cd and click on power and restart
   while holding shift key.
5. then click on "usb" and then click on first option that is
   available. (not sure what it says)
6. then click on try ubuntu or install ubuntu.
7. then follow the steps. in step 3 (i think) it will give you options
   to clear hard dive (i.e. delete ubuntu) or other. choose other.
8. the give the following memory for each: ext4 / :40gb, ext4 /home:
   50gb, ext2 /boot: 500mb and downset boot thing to boot partiton.
9. then you are done. just follow steps.

If you are using windows 7 or lower wawtch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeSaVzyPY8k) it should guid you through the process.

hope it was helpful.

Comment: What about SWAP???

Comment: go through [this](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-swap-what-is.html) and [this](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space). im not sure how i did it.