# How to install ubuntu in my laptop? Where from I can get it? Is it free? What apps or software are required?

Tags: system-installation

How to install ubuntu in my laptop? 
Where from I can get it?
Is it free? 
What apps or software are required?
I am using HP pavilion with Windows 8.1 Original Ver.

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/469697/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-windows-8/469722#469722 which could help you with some idea.

Answer (score 1):

So in order:

Get it from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop 
What apps are required? None, you can either install Ubuntu (it will replace Windows 8.1 if you don't have a dual boot though) or launch it as a live cd to test before installing. Either way, you need to "boot" with the CD.

Basically, juste download the file from the official website, burn it on a CD (using Nero or whatever software), put it in your optical drive, reboot the machine and chose to boot from the CD.

More informations here: 
Live CD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD

There you go, hope it helps ;)